# How to validate message origin and possibility of message replay from WSDL

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have created a WCF service for message level security using certificate and hosted in IIS. My requirement is to read the service URL, download the WSDL and validate message origin and possibility of message replay.

Here is my WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:ProtectionToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
<sp:BootstrapPolicy>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:SymmetricBinding>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:ProtectionToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<mssp:SslContextToken xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
<mssp:RequireClientCertificate/>
</wsp:Policy>
</mssp:SslContextToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:ProtectionToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:EncryptSignature/>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SymmetricBinding>
<sp:Wss11>
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:BootstrapPolicy>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SecureConversationToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:ProtectionToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:EncryptSignature/>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SymmetricBinding>
<sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_Input_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_output_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_Input_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_output_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1000/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1000/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1000/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfMessageSecurityServer"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContractResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IService1">
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_policy"/>
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetData">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_Input_policy"/>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetData_output_policy"/>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_Input_policy"/>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_output_policy"/>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service1">
<wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IService1">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:1000/Service1.svc"/>
<wsa10:EndpointReference>
<wsa10:Address>http://localhost:1000/Service1.svc</wsa10:Address>
<Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>
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
</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Identity>
</wsa10:EndpointReference>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.